# SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php at line 219

Tags: php, xampp, codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter show this problem: SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php at line 219.
I already added extension=intl to php.ini file. But the error still.
Error :

**The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded:
intl.**

**1. SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php : 219  -CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException::forMissingExtension ( arguments )**

```
212         foreach ($requiredExtensions as $extension) {
213             if (! extension_loaded($extension)) {
214                 $missingExtensions[] = $extension;
215             }
216         }
217 
218         if ($missingExtensions !== []) {
219             throw FrameworkException::forMissingExtension(implode(', ', $missingExtensions));
220         }
221     }
222 
223     /**
224      * Initializes Kint
225      */
226     protected function initializeKint()
```

**2. SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php : 177   —  CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->resolvePlatformExtensions ()**

```
170         $this->bootstrapEnvironment();
171 
172         // Setup Exception Handling
173         Services::exceptions()->initialize();
174 
175         // Run this check for manual installations
176         if (! is_file(COMPOSER_PATH)) {
177             $this->resolvePlatformExtensions(); // @codeCoverageIgnore
178         }
179 
180         // Set default locale on the server
181         locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
182 
183         // Set default timezone on the server
184         date_default_timezone_set($this->config->appTimezone ?? 'UTC');
```

**3. SYSTEMPATH/bootstrap.php : 146   —  CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize ()**

```
139  *
140  * The CodeIgniter class contains the core functionality to make
141  * the application run, and does all of the dirty work to get
142  * the pieces all working together.
143  */
144 
145 $app = Services::codeigniter();
146 $app->initialize();
147 
148 return $app;
149
```

**4. require FCPATH/index.php   —   require()**

I already add the extension in php.ini :

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: You will probably find you have not updated the php.ini file that is actually being used. Run `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` to give you a better idea - that will also tell you which php.ini is being used and therefore needs updating.

Comment: I checked which php.ini is being used and it tells the file that I have already added extension=php_intl.dll is that used.

Answer (score 1):

Locate php.ini and then just remove ";" in the extension=intl line

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Locate php.ini and then just remove ";" in the extension=intl line.

Then go to the XAMPP control panel and clicking on Stop, then Restart, on the Apache line Service.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31671519)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that error by install php-xml module
ubuntu : #apt-get install php-xml

env php 8.1.6 / CI 4.1.9

Comment: If intl extension does not solve the issue, my thought CI needs a XML parser